# How to align equations in align* like align, but without numbers?

Tags: align, alignment, gather

Sorry if the question is worded a bit weirdly, but basically, I like how the text looks when it's centered nicely using align, but I don't like the equation numbering on the right hand side of it. I tried using align*, but it ended up shifting everything over to the right hand side.  Here's what I have right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,graphicx,pifont,enumitem}

\begin{gather*}
        (a-b) = nyx \\
        \text{Because } yx \text{ is still some variable, we will denote it with } x \text{ to make our life easier.} \\
    \begin{align}
        & \Rightarrow (a-b) = nx \\
        & \Rightarrow n \,|\, (a-b) \\
        & \Rightarrow a \equiv b \Mod{n}
    \end{align}
\end{gather*}
```

This gives me something that lines up nicely, but has numbers on the right hand side. What can I do to get rid of the equation numbers?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So you want to remove the equation numbers without using `align*`?

Comment: You can use \nonumber to specify non-numbers in each split equation used in align environment.

Comment: the only difference between `align*` and `align` is that it omits the numbers, if the alignment changed to the right then you had an error but hard to say as you did not show that code, perhaps you forgot the `&` on each line.

Comment: you can not nest `align` or `align*` inside `gather*` all three are top level environments that _start_ display math alignments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Erm... "_The chief exception is that `align` and most of its variants can be used inside the `gather` environment._" Which always baffled me `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but may help others to find out what you really want. `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` were missing, and `\Mod` not defined. Perhaps more importantly I do not understand what you mean with your statement on `align*`. There was IMHO no need for `gather` and no need to write the text in such a complicated way.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,graphicx,pifont,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Suggestions by @daleif and @DavidCarlisle}:
\[
        (a-b) = nyx \]
Because $yx$ is still some variable, we will denote it with $x$ to make our life
easier.
\begin{align*}
         \Rightarrow &\quad(a-b) = nx \\
         \Rightarrow &\quad n \mid (a-b) \\
         \Rightarrow &\quad a \equiv b \mod n
\end{align*}

I personally would add thin spaces indicating the suppressed multiplication
signs.
\[
        (a-b) = n\,y\,x \]
Because $y\,x$ is still some variable, we will denote it with $x$ to make our life
easier.
\begin{align*}
         \Rightarrow &\quad(a-b) = n\,x \\
         \Rightarrow &\quad n \mid (a-b) \\
         \Rightarrow &\quad a \equiv b \mod n
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped out a bunch.  I was looking through different sources so I guess that's why I had written it so complicated.

Comment: Probably looks better with at least a quad of space before the &'s

Comment: the space around the arrow is too tight because you have used `\Rightarrow &` rather than `&\Rightarrow `, and `\mid` would be better than `\,|\,`

Comment: @daleif Better now?

Comment: +1, I don't better, though I don't agree on the adding space between variables, I see no need for it, and it makes the code for the formulas unnecessary complicated. Also I often create a new macro called `\divides` that is just `\mid`, then the source `n \divides (a-b)` makes sense on its own. If you do not know `\mid` then the code `n \mid (a-b)` is confusing. Writing math is often like this, and it might sometimes be a good idea to have personal names for symbols, names that makes more sense in the field one is using them in.

Comment: @daleif That's why I wrote that I personally would do it. And I agree with what you write on `\divide`, but my post is not an introduction to typesetting, just to say that there is no issue with `align*` and that there are simpler ways to write the text. BTW, I really like the mathtools package!

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want to align the various formulas with each other. Here I make the `\Rightarrow\quad` “transparent” (this assumes the formulas are not too wide so the symbol will not go past the left margin).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\follows}{\mathllap{\Rightarrow\quad}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& (a-b) = nyx \\
\shortintertext{Because $yx$ is still some variable, we will denote it
with $x$ to make our life easier.}
\follows & (a-b) = nx \\
\follows & n \mid (a-b) \\
\follows & a \equiv b \pmod{n}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]